# How to exclude an element from css?

Tags: html, css, tags

Note:
I've looked around at other threads, but I can't seem to get the answers there to work.

I've been trying to exclude "#menu" from the margin property in "body{}" so that it doesn't overlap the text.

My code:

```
body {
    text-align: center;
    background: black;
    background: url("http://tuxlink.files.wordpress.com/2010/04/snow-leopard-server-wallpaper.jpg");
    font-family: Helvetica;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: black;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 15%;
}

#menu{
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    position: fixed;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    border: 5px;
    background-color: grey;
    background-size: contain;
    border-style: ridge;
    border-color: grey;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a margin on #menu?

Comment: You should at least mention the “threads” (questions) you have looked at and specify why the answers given were not satisfactory. You surely cannot “exclude an element from CSS” (CSS has no elements, it has just selectors that match HTML or XML elements), and the text “to exclude "#menu" from the margin property in "body{}" so that it doesn't overlap the text” is not a problem description.

Answer (score 0):

Override the CSS from the body with the CSS for the menu:

```
#menu { border: none; border-width: 5px; }
```

Add anything else you might need in there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make the margin on `#menu` be reset to the default value, you can add `margin: none;` to your CSS, so that it looks something like this:

```
body {
    text-align: center;
    background: black;
    background: url("http://tuxlink.files.wordpress.com/2010/04/snow-leopard-server-wallpaper.jpg");
    font-family: Helvetica;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: black;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 15%;
}

#menu{
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    position: fixed;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    border: 5px;
    background-color: grey;
    background-size: contain;
    border-style: ridge;
    border-color: grey;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    margin: none;
}
```

That should do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

probably it was what inside your #menu

```
#menu{
position:absolute;  <-- this are interfering with your margins
color:white;        
position:fixed;     <-- this are interfering with your margins
float:left;         <-- this are interfering with your margins
margin: none;       <-- remove that and try set the margin here (eg: margin: 10px;)
}
```